# Populating list of users from IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list in my Razor page.  To do this, I created a view model that will have a list of users.  The list of users needs to be populated from `IdentityDbContext`.

I'm going through all the examples posted by other users and the issue I'm having is defining the correct variables.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**AppDbContext.cs**

```cs
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

**ProcessCreateViewModel.cs**

```cs
public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
public string User { get; set; }
```

**ProcessController.cs**

```cs
public IActionResult CreateProcess()
{
    var context = new AppDbContext();
    var processCreateViewModel = new ProcessCreateViewModel()
    {
        Users = context.Users.ToList()
    };            
    return View(processCreateViewModel);
}
```

**CreateProcess.cshtml**

```html
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.User, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-5">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.User, new SelectList(Model.Users, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "ApplicationUser" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the line in `ProcessController.cs`,
`var context = new AppDbContext();`

return an error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'options'

I have no idea how to fix or change my approach to get the user loaded into a list on my ViewModel so that I can use it in a dropdown list on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it like this: `services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

As well why are you initializing a new isntance of DB context, you need to dependecy inject the Db context, as you are initializing it for DI with this line `services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`, then everything should be fine, for example:

```
public class YourController {

public YourController (YourDbContext context){
//.. Assign here and then reuse in controller end points
}

}
```

Otherwise you are trying to initialize the DBContext yourself and the DbContext as it says does not have a default constructor to address to.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!! You were correct, I only had to dependency inject the Db context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parameterless constructor in "AppDbContext.cs"? try adding the following:

```
    public AppDbContext()
    {
    }
```